# Share Ubuntu internet connection to other devices via Wi-Fi

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I'm new to Ubuntu 10.04 and also don't have much experience in networks.

I want to share my Internet connection with other devices (Laptop with Windows) via Wi-Fi. All I have is Ubuntu 10.04, eth0 and wlan0 (Wi-Fi adapter: D-link USB Modem).

What should I do?

Comment: So haven't you found any tutorials yet, tried anything?

Comment: i googled, but many tutorials Comment mode, I try seach tutorial with desktop konfigure ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be not too difficult to make a Linux access point. Here are two sites that explain how to do that.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wi...essAccessPoint

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1488953